# how to convert dataframe to list and then to corpus?what is differnce between Vcorpus and Corpus in R?

Tags: r, twitter, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

i am new to r learning sentiment analysis using twitter tweets using R.
when i extract tweets in r they are in list class type but, then i need to convert them to dataframe to consider only one column with text type only because other types are irrelevant for my study like screenname, created, replyToSID, and others, and hence, i created dataframe and kept only one column with text.

but, when i convert the dataframe in list to further convert it into corpus for data cleaning using tm. i am getting output i expect in single list to do my study. below are my code lines..

```
covid_tweets <- searchTwitter('#COVID-19', n = 100, since = '2020-02-01')
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df_tweets <- twListToDF(covid_tweets)
df_text_tweets <- df_tweets[-c(2:16)]
View(df_text_tweets)

library(BBmisc)
data<-convertRowsToList(df_text_tweets)
datacorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data))

Covid_data<-tm_map(datacorpus, stripWhitespace)
Covid_data<-tm_map(Covid_data,tolower)
Covid_data<-tm_map(Covid_data,removeNumbers)
Covid_data<-tm_map(Covid_data,removePunctuation)
Covid_data<-tm_map(Covid_data,removeWords, stopwords('english'))
```

output is not satisfactory.. when i use view function i can see 1 with 2 list i.e. content and metadata. 
I just want only text in the output in a list form..

if any further information needed please, free to ask me..or explain me how i simply convert the tweets into dataframe then to list followed by creating corpus and cleaning data using tm. Much appreciated in advance.

attached, the screenshots

[output of df tweets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzuCj.png)
[code i ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEvdx.png)

Comment: Try adding R to the question tags for more visibility

Comment: If you want to learn about sentiment analysis I can recommend https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html. It